Normalizers grow in $p$-groups
Let $G$ be a $p$-group, i.e. $|G|=p^n$. Let $H < G$. Then $H< N_G(H)$.
I saw a solution to this and I'm wondering if I've found a simpler solution. First, I will present the solution that I found (I forget where, maybe on this site).
Solution.
Induct on $n$. If $n=1$, then $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_p$ and it's clear that $1=H < G = N_G(H)$. Now, suppose the result holds for all values less than $n$. I now show the result for $n$.
So, $|G| = p^n$. Toward a contradiction, suppose $N_G(H)=H$. Now, we note that $Z(G) \subseteq N_G(H)$ always and so $Z(G) \trianglelefteq H$. $Z(G) \neq 1$ because $G$ is a $p$-group, which means that $H/Z(G)$ satisfies the inductive hypothesis. (I will now use $Z:=Z(G)$) Now, we have
$$H/Z < N(H/Z) \tag{$\star$}$$
which means there exists a class $\overline{x} \in (G/Z) \setminus(H/Z)$ so that
$$\overline{x}(H/Z)\overline{x}^{-1} = H/Z$$
$$\implies \, \forall \, \, h \in H, \hspace{0.8cm} \overline{x} (hZ)\overline{x}^{-1} = xhx^{-1}Z= h_1Z \hspace{0.8cm} \mathrm{for \, \, some} \, \, h_1 \in H$$
$$\exists \, z ,z_1 \in Z, \hspace{0.8cm} xhx^{-1}z=h_1z_1$$
$$\implies xhx^{-1}=h_1z_1z^{-1}$$
As $Z(G) \subseteq H$, the RHS is in $H$, which means the LHS is in $H$. Then $x \in N_G(H)=H$, a contradiction. Thus, it must be the case that $H < N_G(H)$.
$$\hspace{10cm} \blacksquare$$
I may have made minor etiquette mishaps in the above proof so please forgive me if so. Now, I really like this proof but I think it can be made simpler. Instead, I would reproduce the proof up to line $(\star)$ and then I would make an addendum to $(\star)$. I would say
$$H/Z < N(H/Z) = H/Z$$
which is impossible. Is there anything wrong with what I've proposed here? It just seems that we can cut out all those extra bits by recalling that $H/Z$ satisfies the inductive hypothesis.

The statement "$H/Z$ satisfies the induction hypothesis" does not help you. That just means that any proper subgroup of $H/Z$ is properly contained in its $(H/Z)$-normalizer.  Presumably you mean $G/Z$, which the proof you are quoting already does as well. And you are not simplifying: you are only omitting an explicit verification that if $M\triangleleft G$ and $M\leq H\leq G$, then $N_{G/M}(H/M) = N_G(H)/M$ when you claim $N(H/Z)=H/Z$, which is what the stuff you are trying to remove does. If you've proven that, sure, you can invoke it, but you didn't simplify anything.

@ArturoMagidin ah yes, that makes perfect sense now. Thank you!
